# Multiple domains resolve to one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cname-record

I have the following scenario:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
```

Whenever someone types www.domain1.com  or www.domain2.com or www.domain3.com she should be redirected to www.domain4.com.

How can i achieve this using CNAME records?

Hosting environment: Shared hoster, IIS7, Websitepanel

Comment: Since you are a webmaster and _not_ the hosting provider, you may find your web hosting questions better answered at our sister site [webmasters.se]. Server Fault is designed for professional system administrators (such as the people you've purchased hosting from) and so the answers we give may not always apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CNAME is the answer here. Ofcourse you can specify those cnames as far as they will point to a certain IP address for hosting those websites. But to achieve your goal you must configure the webserver properly. Here comes the "Alias" in the (for example) apache2 configuration file for the domain4.com. 
It will look somethin like the following :

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain4.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com www.domain2.com www.domain3.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain4.com (or the valid path for the domain)
        <Directory />
                Options
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
...........................
```

Comment: +1. Cname records never will issue a redirect for the browser, and that is what needed here.

Answer (score 1):

To do this using CNAME records you will have to

- Assign a DNS A record to www.domain4.com
- Assign CNAME records to www.domain1.com etc pointing to www.domain4.com.

How you do this depends on how your DNS is managed for each domain but DNS providers typically have a web based form that allows you to make changes.

Once you've done that you need to configure your web server to provide the content. This would normally be done by configuring NameBasedVirtual hosting.